# How can I trigger the OpenLayers 3 full screen event?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm attempting to trigger my OpenLayers 3 map to become full screen within the code but I'm not having much luck.

I have something along the lines of:

```
var fullScreenControl = new ol.control.FullScreen()

// Create map in between using fullScreenControl

fullScreenControl.changed();
```

The code accomplishes nothing though. I tried fullScreenControl.dispatchEvent('change'); also without luck. I'm guessing it's not too tricky, but all the other questions seem to revolve around detecting the event rather than triggering it.

Comment: If you don't find any solution for this, think about libraries that trigger full screen behavior for HTML elements, like https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js, or just read this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Answer (score 3):

ol3 uses the "HTML5" Fullscreen API to toggle the map in full screen mode. I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish, but there are different ways to toggle the fullscreen.

Here is a pure js method to set your map on full screen:

```
function setMapToFullScreen(){
  //if your map element id is other than 'map' change it here
        var elem = document.getElementById('map');
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }   
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/uupk6b6g/) to see it in action.

If you plan to attach the fullscreen functionality in a DOM element outside the map you can always use `target` option during fullscreen initialisation. If you just want to do it programmatically, then use the function above. It depends on what you want to achieve.